# Gdata API Installation

Tags: python, unix, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm using Python 2.7 on OSX with the Eclipse PyDev IDE. I've never worked with an API before, but I need to use the google calendar API with a Python application I'm developing. I downloaded the latest gdata module from Google and installed it using this line in Terminal while in the directory into which I downloaded the gdata folder (Downloads):

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

It seemed to install everything into a Python directory deep within my machine's Library, no errors were given. However, now when I attempt to run a program with the following import commands:

```
import gdata.calendar.data
import gdata.calendar.client
import gdata.acl.data
import atom
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named gdata.calendar.data
```

Clearly indicating I have done something wrong on the install. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably installed, but you haven't told Eclipse where to look for `gdata`.

Right click on the project in Eclipse and choose `Properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH -> Source Folders` and click "Add source folder".

The folder will (probably) be in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gdata`, depending on the version and where you installed it. It might be somewhere else, like `dist-packages` instead of `site-packages`, but once you find it and add the folder inside Eclipse, the imports should work.

**Edit**: Don't forget to do the same for `atom`, too.

Comment: Is it necessary to go through this process for every project in Eclipse, or is there a way to get PyDev to find this by default for each project?

Comment: You could modify your `PYTHONPATH` directly - put the line `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/package` into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Comment: On Mac, it might be `~/.bash_profile`. And you'll have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` (or whichever one you have/use) in a terminal to make your environment update.

Comment: Forget the last two comments, you can do it directly inside Eclipse. Go to `Eclipse -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python -> Libraries` and add the appropriate folders.

Comment: Perfect. However, I think my install error has occurred somewhere before then. I've looked through my Library files and I cannot find any of the gdata library files. I've tried to run sudo python setup.py install again, but nothing changes. I'm totally stuck, because my unix knowledge is essentially zilch.

Comment: Strange. Have you looked carefully at the installation output to make sure there are no errors? After running the same command as you, I have a `gdata` and `atom` folder inside `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the folder from where I'm running the commands? I just downloaded gdata and put it in my Downloads folder.

Comment: I am getting "UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'."

Comment: First, add the line `from setuptools import setup` to the top of your `setup.py`. Then, open a python interpreter (type `python` in a terminal) and try to `import gdata`. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Well, when I try to run setup.py, I get an error stating that there is "no module named setuptools." When I type import gdata into the python interpreter from terminal, nothing happens -- I get no errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21733/discussion-between-mccrustin-and-user1427661)